# H264 decoder in opencv for real time video transmission

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, h.264

I am writing a client-server application which does real time video transmission from an android based phone to a server. The captured video from the phone camera is encoded using the android provided h264 encoder and transmitted via UDP socket. The frames are not RTP encapsulated. I need it to reduce the overhead and hence the delay.
On the receiver, I need to decode the incoming encoded frame. The data being sent on the UDP socket not only contains the encoded frame but some other information related to the frame as a part of its header. Each frame is encoded as an nal unit.

I am able to retrieve the frames from the received packet as a byte array. I can save this byte array as raw h264 file and playback using vlc and everything works fine. 
However, I need to do some processing on this frame and hence need to use it with opencv.
Can anyone help me with decoding a raw h264 byte array in opencv?
Can ffmpeg be used for this?

Comment: In the latest opencv, the h.264 decoder is absent

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: ffmpeg and ffplay will work directly. I remember Opencv can be built on top of those 2. so shouldn`t be difficult to use the FFMEPG/FFSHOW plug in to convert to cv::Mat. Follow the docuemnts

> OpenCV can use the FFmpeg library (http://ffmpeg.org/) as backend to
>   record, convert and stream audio and video. FFMpeg is a complete,
>   cross-reference solution. If you enable FFmpeg while configuring
>   OpenCV than CMake will download and install the binaries in
>   OPENCV_SOURCE_CODE/3rdparty/ffmpeg/. To use FFMpeg at runtime, you
>   must deploy the FFMepg binaries with your application.
>
> https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html

Last time, I have to play with DJI PSDK. And they only allow stream at UDP port  udp://192.168.5.293:23003 with H.264
So I wrote a simple ffmpeg interface to stream to the PSDK. But I have to debug it beforehand.  So I use ffplay to show this network stream to proof it is working. This is the script to show the stream. So you have to work on top of this to work as opencv plugin

```
ffplay -f h264 -i udp://192.168.1.45:23003
```